# How to pass value from a method to another method

Tags: android

```
            import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.Dialog;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.MenuItem;
            import android.view.MotionEvent;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
            import android.widget.*;
            import android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;

            public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnValueChangeListener {

                EditText push_ups, sit_ups;
                NumberPicker np;
                Button calculate;
                final Context context = this;
                CheckBox checkbox;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
                    push_ups = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pushups);
                    sit_ups = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.situps);
                    np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.np1);
                    checkbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

                    String[] values = {"some array"};       
                    np.setMaxValue(values.length-1);
                    np.setMinValue(0);
                    np.setDisplayedValues(values);       
                    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
```

//calculateButton runs when I click the "calculate" Button

```
                    calculateButton();

                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
                    layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            hideKeyboard();
                            return false;
                        }

                    }); 
                }


                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }

                /**
                 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
                 */
                public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

                    public PlaceholderFragment() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                                false);
                        return rootView;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                }

                private void hideKeyboard() {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(push_ups.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }

                public int calculatePushups() {
                    int pushupScore = 0;
                    int ageGroup = Integer.parseInt(null, np.getValue());
                    int pushupReps = Integer.parseInt(push_ups.getText().toString());
                    final int [][] pushupTable = {"some 2D array"};

                    if (pushupReps<= 60) {
                        pushupScore = pushupTable[pushupReps][ageGroup];
                    } else {
                        pushupScore = 60;
                    }
                return pushupScore;
                }

                public int calculateSitups() {
                    final int [][] situpTable = {"some 2D array"};
                    return 0;

                }

                private void normalRun() {

                }

                private void specialRun() {

                }

                private void calculateRun() {
                    if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
                        specialRun();
                    }
                    else {
                        normalRun();
                    }
                }

                private void calculateScore() {
                    calculatePushups();
                    calculateSitups();
                    calculateRun();
                }
                public void calculateButton() {

                    final TextView pus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pushup_score);

                    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // custom dialog
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);
                            dialog.setTitle("Score");
```

I am trying to set the TextView to display the pushupScore here but it seems I am trying to pass a result from another method to this. I have no idea how to get it around still new with android,

```
                            //pus.setText(pushupScore);

                            pus.setText(String.valueOf(calculatePushups()));

                            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
                            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                            dialog.show();
                          }
                        });
                }
            }
```

Here's my dialog XML code:

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                        android:text="Push-ups: "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pushup_score"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="4.97"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="Sit-ups: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="2.4km Run: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="Award: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_ok"
                    style="@style/AppTheme"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="Ok" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Couldn't understand what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are returning the pushupScore in calculatePushups so just write:

```
pus.setText(String.valueOf(calculatePushups()));
```

And btw this is not a android mechanism, this is simple java return usage:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: I tried your code, but the app crashes when "Calculate" button is clicked. I have assigned empty methods to run when the button is clicked, is that the reason why it crashed?

Comment: could you post the stack-trace or atleast your "new" code?

Comment: posted my new code.. basically added your line. The app works fine when that line was commented out.

Comment: so theres a mistake in calculatePushUps(). Try: int ageGroup = np.getValue();

Comment: Ok so it works now, I got the score calculated from the ageGroup and input value. The thing now is that the score is display in my linear layout and not the dialog. How do I change the "findViewById" correctly?

Comment: you need to use the findViewById of the dialog. TextView pushupScore = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pushup_score). This way you get the TextView of the dialog.xml .

Answer (score 0):

You left out quite a bit of your code so I'm not sure where your problem is, but if you could follow these steps and let me know if you're getting any errors etc? Anyway, here is what you need to have:

Make sure your Activity implements OnClickListener:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnValueChangeListener {
    //...
}
```

Within the activity's overridden onCreate() method, register the activity as the handler:

```
calculate = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
calculate.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Within `MainActivity`, have the handler like so:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId(){
        case R.id.dialog_ok:
            push_ups.setText("" + calculatePushups());
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Perhaps you should change your `EditText` into a `TextView`, the `EditText` isn't necessary and might be causing problems?

Is this what you were after?